# Confused with a proof of Gauss's lemma about polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

So I have been trying to understand a proof of Gauss's lemma which states a polynomial with integer coefficients is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. I have been able to understand the majority of the proof, but the part that I do not understand is this:

> Suppose $$g_1 = a_0 + a_1X + \cdots + a_lX^l \textrm{  and } g_2 = b_0 + b_1X + \cdots + b_mX^m$$
> for some coefficients $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{Z}.$ We claim that $p$ either divides all the $a_i$ or divides all the $b_i$. If not, we can assume that $p$ divides $a_0, a_1, \ldots a_{j-1}$ but does not divide $a_j$ and that $p$ divides $b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_{k-1}$ but does not divide $b_k$.

In this proof, $p$ just stands for a prime number. The proof continues on and shows that if $p$ really divides $a_0, a_1, \ldots a_{j-1}$ but does not divide $a_j$ and that $p$ divides $b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_{k-1}$ but does not divide $b_k$, then we would arrive at a contradiction. The part that I don't understand is why do we assume that $p$ divides $a_0, a_1, \ldots a_{j-1}$ but does not divide $a_j$ and that $p$ divides $b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_{k-1}$ but does not divide $b_k$? Why can't we assume that, for example, every other element $a_0, a_2, \ldots$ are divisible by $p$? Why exactly this order?

For more details about this proof one can view [http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~martyn/5836/MT5836lecturenotes.pdf](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/%7Emartyn/5836/MT5836lecturenotes.pdf) at
page 12 to 13.

Comment: For context, the preceding line in the paper states that $p$ divides $g_1(X)g_2(X)$.

Comment: One picks the _smallest_ index such that $p$ doesn't divide $a_j$ and $b_k$ respectively, whether $p$ divides coefficients with larger index, and if so, which, doesn't matter at all. So if $p$ divides $a_0$ and $a_2$ but not $a_1$, one picks $j = 1$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: the English possessive doesn't use an s for names ending in s, it  uses just the apostrophe.

Comment: @Bernard: Not according to the Chicago Manual of Style. I wrote a paper with "Gauss's Lemma" in the title several years ago, and I looked it up very carefully. The only exception is for names that end in an "eeze" sound (like Xerxes), and, for historical reason, "Jesus". The Monthly published it with that spelling, so...

Comment: @Bernard: Here's the [general rule](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch07/psec016.html); here's the [proper noun rule](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch07/psec017.html) (note, e.g., "Borges's" and "Kansas's"); rule for [names ending in an unpronounced s](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch07/psec018.html); [exception for names ending in *eez*](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch07/psec019.html).

Comment: @Bernard: There is an exception, but it's for [nouns whose singular form ends in *s* and is the same as the plural](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch07/psec020.html). You are following [an alternative practice](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch07/psec022.html)

Comment: Okay, @Daniel Fischer I understand that now! So if, for example, $a_0$ was not divisible by $p$ then one would set $j = 0$. That would make $a_0$ divisible and the rest of the $a_i$ would be free to choose. Am I right about this?

Comment: I think I write in english, not in american.

Comment: @gabbe1237 I think in your third sentence you meant "That would make $a_0$ *not* divisible ...". Then yes, that's more or less right, only the $a_i$ are given, we can't choose them. But which, if any, of the $a_i$ with higher index are divisible by $p$ doesn't matter.

Comment: @Bernard: The [Oxford University Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide%20%28updated%20Hilary%20term%202016%29.pdf) page 9 of the file, says "If a name already ends in **s** or **z** and would be difficult to pronounce if 's were added at the end, consider rearranging the sentence to avoid the difficulty" and gives an example with "Jesus's" being what you would be trying to avoid by dropping the possesive entirely.  Exception for some place names, with no rules to it.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Okay I think that I get it now! Perhaps I expressed myself wrong, you clearly can not "choose" and, as you mentioned, it is of no interest to us whether higher index $a$'s are divisible or not. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bernard: And the [Cambridge University Style Guide](https://www.cam.ac.uk/brand-resources/editorial-style-guide) states "When a noun ends with an s and the final syllable is pronounced, the possessive s is added, eg Thomas's lunch, Dr Huw Jones's research, Octopus's Garden." (under "Punctuation", subheading "Apostrophes")

Comment: @gabbe1237: Sorry for the hijack.$j$ is the least index for which $p$ does not divide $a_j$; $k$ is the least index for which $p$ does not divide $b_k$. Both exist since we are assuming $p$ does not divide all the $a$s, so the set of indices for which $p$ does not divide the corresponding $a$ is nonempty, and thus has a least element. Symmetrically with $k$.